# Center button inside grandparent center aligned flex div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Title sounds confusing but it's hard to word!

How would I centre align the `a` inside the `.feature-inner` div? Whenever I use the usual `margin: 0 auto; display: block;` it just stretches the link to be the full width of the `div`.

Here's my HTML:

```css
#feature {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: $titlefont;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.top {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.bottom {
  font-weight: 100;
}

a {
  background-color: $brandGreen;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: $font;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #717171;
}
```

```html
<div id="feature">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="feature-inner">
      <h1 class="top">My Title</h1>
      <h1 class="bottom">My Sub title</h1>
      <a href="">My button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex tag : *pache Flex [NOT CSS FLEXBOX] is a framework for developing Rich Internet Applications that run in Flash Player or Adobe Air. Originally designed by Adobe,* Please pay attention to the tag description before using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```css
#feature {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: $titlefont;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.top {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.bottom {
  font-weight: 100;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center; //center the button text vertically
  width: 100px; //set the width of button
  height: 30px; //set the height of button
  line-height: 30px; //when set same as height makes the button text centered horizontally
  margin: 0 auto; //center the whole button
  background-color: $brandGreen;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: $font;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #717171;
}
```

```html
<div id="feature">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="feature-inner">
      <h1 class="top">My Title</h1>
      <h1 class="bottom">My Sub title</h1>
      <a href="">My button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/zehogubaja/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Ahh yes, didn't realise you had to force the width of the button, thanks!